# Resistance of a washer with square cross sectional area

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrical-resistance

Consider a resistor in the shape of a washer with resistivity $\rho$. It has a square cross sectional area $A$ and inner radius $a$ and outer radius $2a$. Find the resistance across the two wires like that shown in [image: Picture].

My attempt was to find a differential element of resistance $dR$ and then integrate. I end up with: $$dR=\frac{\rho 2\pi r}{2\pi r dr}=\frac{\rho}{dr}$$ which doesn't seem to be making sense since I will have to add up $\frac{1}{dr}$ which is adding infinities.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the elements are in parallel so you must add together $\frac {1}{dR}$

Answer (score 0):

When I find out the resistance of a wire (a normal one, that is), We mechanically take the cross sectional area A of the wire as it is, the length l, and the resistivity. Now, we never considered elemental resistance while computing the resistance of such a wire. This is mainly because how the resistance varies with length or cross-sectional area is not considered,and is assumed to be constant. The above problem consists of a wire with a square face, length equal to the circumference, and resistance is a constant function w.r.t length and area (i.e. rho). So the resistance should simply be resistivity*length divided by cross section. **By the way, let me point out that the cross section area should be the area of the square face.**
[image] Always consider the cross sectional area to be the region 'surrounding' the current, like a tunnel around your car. Here, it's a tunnel with a square opening. Thanks.

Comment: The inner edge of your CSA will travel a shorter distance than the outer edge.